# Selenium not clicking 'Log In' button on Discover website login

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to build a Python script that will automatically log me into my Discover CC webpage.  I got the username and password to enter themselves (CC info code not shown here for security reasons) but I can't get selenium to hit the 'Log In' button.

Here's the [Discover](https://www.discover.com/) webpage I'm using.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('https://www.discover.com/')

time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element_by_id('log-in-button').click()
```

Here's the error Sublime Text 3 gives me:
"selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element  could not be scrolled into view"

The button is clearly visible so I'm not sure why it can't see it.  I also gave the webpage some time to load before I try hitting the Log In button.  Side note: if I let the script enter the username and password and I manually hit 'Log In' it logs me in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the last line with:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='log-in-button' and @class='btn-primary log-in-button right']").click()`

Comment: Thanks! I put it in the script that includes my CC information and it successfully logs in.  I had no idea I had to include 'class' as well.  Mind commenting on why I had to use x-path instead of ID and why class had to be included?

Comment: I used xpath because it's built for searching through HTML, and class because there was another element with the ID 'login-in-button'.

Comment: Ok. Thanks again.  I'll keep that in mind for future projects.

Comment: Yeah, no problem. Would you mind accepting my answer?